# Copy the highlighted pattern in gvim

Tags: unix, vim

Lets say, I highlighted (matched) text  present in brackets  using

```
/(.*)
```

Now, how to copy  the highlighted text only (i.e matching pattern, not entire line)  into a buffer, so that I paste it some where.

Comment: Have you tried yanking the text (`y`)?

Comment: Yes, i copying the entire line, it  needed only  that highlited pattern(words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple approaches are presented in [this Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard). The simplest approach is the following custom command:

```
function! CopyMatches(reg)
    let hits = []
    %s//\=len(add(hits, submatch(0))) ? submatch(0) : ''/ge
    let reg = empty(a:reg) ? '+' : a:reg
    execute 'let @'.reg.' = join(hits, "\n") . "\n"'
endfunction
command! -register CopyMatches call CopyMatches(<q-reg>)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you search, you can use the `e` flag to motion to the end of the match. So if I understand your question correctly, if you searched using eg.:

```
/bar
```

And you wish to copy it, use:

```
y//e
```

This will yank using the previous search pattern until the end of the match.

Comment: Thanks, But its copied only the 1st match into buffer, but not all

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to combine every `(foo)` in the buffer in one register (which would look like `(foo)(bar)(baz)…`) or do you want to yank a single `(foo)` that you matched?

The last is done with `ya(` if you want the parenthesis or `yi(` if you only want what's between.

Ingo's answer takes care of the former.